# Yii use ItemAlias in CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii's 'ItemAlias' function to give a custom name to a value, like this:

```
<?php
public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL) {
    $_items = array(

        'currency' => array(
            '1'=>'US Dollar',
            '2'=>'Euro',
            '3'=>'GB Pound',
            '4'=>'Chinese RMB',
            '5'=>'Singaporese Dollar'
        )
    );
    if (isset($code))
        return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] : false;
    else
        return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
}
?>
```

Now, in CGridView, it currently displays the number (key) of the currency which it found in the database, but I want to display it's label. The CGridView is generated like this:

```
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'purchases-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
  'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'currency',
    [..etc]
```

Can someone point me into the right direction to display the label instead of the key of the value? Thanks!

Comment: `itemAlias` is not a Yii feature. Do you use any extension that provides it or did you maybe write a `getCurrency()` getter method? If the latter, you should show it.

Comment: It's part of the model generated by GII. Sorry, I am a bit inexperienced with Yii, this is a practise project :-)

Comment: You must use some extension. You won't find `itemAlias` anywhere in the Yii source files (incl. gii). (Try `grep -r itemAlias path/to/framework`).

Comment: Ah I see, I copied it from the 'user' module. Nevermind, I will write a function like getCurrency() as Michael Härtl suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the limited code you showed this is what I think you want if `itemAlias()` is a function built into your model:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'purchases-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
  'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'name' => 'currency',
      'value' => '$data->itemAlias("currency",$data->currency)',
    ),
    ...
```

If it is some generic function somewhere not part of your model you would do this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'purchases-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
  'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'name' => 'currency',
      'value' => 'itemAlias("currency",$data->currency)',
    ),
    ...
```